# Cassandra Datastax Node.js driver can't find keyspace

Tags: node.js, cassandra, datastax, cassandra-3.0, datastax-node-driver

Just installed Cassandra (3.11.1) and Datastax node.js driver (3.3.0).

Created a simple structure:

```
CREATE KEYSPACE CaseBox
   WITH REPLICATION={
     'class': 'SimpleStrategy',
     'replication_factor': 1};
USE CaseBox;

CREATE TABLE Regions (
    regionId int,
    name varchar,
    PRIMARY KEY ((regionId))
);
```

Trying connect to the keyspace with no success:

```
const client = new cassandra.Client({
  contactPoints: ['localhost'],
  keyspace: 'CaseBox'
});

await client.connect();
```

Error: `Keyspace 'CaseBox' does not exist`.
If I change the desired kayspace to `system` it works.
What's wrong? Please assist.

You can find my full Cassandra config, CQL and js scripts [here](https://gist.github.com/milichev/c310ffd15f8e36cf96af3de42b9029eb).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Keyspace names are forced lower case when unquoted in CQL](http://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.3/cql/cql_reference/cqlCreateKeyspace.html).

Use `CREATE KEYSPACE "CaseBox"` in CQL or `keyspace: 'casebox'` in Node.

Generally just use `snake_case` names as you won't get trapped like this as often.